# The char str[700] initializing in C++ string

Tags: c++, initialization

How do we have char str[700] initializing into C++ string syntax?

```
#include <string>
int main(){
  //...
  char str[700];
   // string eqivalent...

 string str;  //...?

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::string has inbuilt constructor doing this work for us.
use it like

```
char *a;
//Processing on character array a
string str(a);
//str now a C++ string equal to a
```

Comment: Use constructors only during declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to just assign values to `string` as it will allocate the memory using internal allocator for you. Or you can just use `reserve()` method to do that before hand:

See:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve

Or using the construtor to assign some defaults:

```
std::string str(700, '\0');
```